# Use Pkcs5 padding With AES encryption in Cryptojs

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I just need to use cryptojs AES encryption but with padding Pkcs5 which i can not find in Cryptjs document, i want to do this because it is desired from the backend.
it worked fine with Pkcs7 and cypher mode ECB, how to convert this function to work with Pkcs5

```
encryptByAES: function (secretPwd) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.encryption_key);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secretPwd, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    console.log('encryptByAES key: ',encrypted.toString());
    return encrypted.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When used with AES there is no difference betwheen **PKCS#5** & **PKCS#7**.

The difference between the PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 padding is the block size it supports. PKCS#5 only works with 8-byte blocks whereas PKCS#7 works with block sizes betwheen 1 and 255 bytes. AES uses block size of 8 bytes.

Comment: There is a difference! PKCS#5 pads at most 64 bits = 8*8 bytes (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898). PKCS#7 pads at most 2040 bits =  255 *
 8 bytes (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315). PKCS#5 should not be used with AES. It was rather created for DES.

Comment: @schirrmacher is right. Please correct this answer.